# What's wrong with my java code

Tags: java

I'm learning java. 
My sample's directory is like the following:

> ./src
>   ./src/yxy
>   ./src/yxy/pack
>   ./src/yxy/pack/testf
>   ./src/yxy/pack/testf/Person.java
>   ./Hello.java
>   ./Hello.class
>
> ./testpack
>   ./testpack/yxy
>   ./testpack/yxy/pack
>   ./testpack/yxy/pack/testf
>   ./testpack/yxy/pack/testf/Person.class
>   ./testpack.jar

The src direcotory is used as a library. It provides the Person class.
The output of the src is located in testpack direcotory.
I generate a testpack.jar according to the testpack direcotory.
The Hello.java is the main java file. It uses the Person class.

The **Person.java** source code is the following:

```
package yxy.pack.testf;

public class Person {
  private String name;

  public Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

The **Hello.java** source code is the following:

```
import java.io.*; //IOException
import java.util.*; //Enumeration

import yxy.pack.testf.Person;

public class Hello{

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException  {
        Person p=new Person("abc");
        Class cls=Person.class;
        ClassLoader clsLoader=cls.getClassLoader();
        String clsFile=cls.getName();
        System.out.println("end");
    }
}
```

I use the following method to generate the testpack.jar under the current directory.

> javac -verbose -d testpack  src\yxy\pack\testf\Person.java
>   cd testpack
>   jar -cvf testpack.jar ./yxy
>   move testpack.jar ./../testpack.jar
>   cd ..

I use the following method to build and run the app:

> javac -classpath .\testpack.jar Hello.java
>   java -classpath .\testpack.jar Hello

this is the error I get:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello  
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Hello  
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)  
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)  
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  
    Could not find the main class: Hello.  Program will exit.
```

I don't why this happen. How can I fix?

> java  Hello

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: yxy/pack/testf/Person

            at Hello.main(Hello.java:10)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: yxy.pack.testf.Person
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            ... 1 more
```

How can I fix this?

===
Anyway, I found out how to fix. Just use the following in cmd.

```
>java -classpath testpack.jar;. Hello
```

I must add testpack.jar and current path . to the classpath.

Comment: What errors are you getting?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: whats the purpose of the code? try to track down which part of the code is not functioning as it should/is giving errors, and just post the 3-4 lines you find.

Comment: Well, if the purpose of your code is to throw exceptions, there's nothing wrong

Comment: Have you tried using an IDE? This will setup your directories and run javac for as required.  All you have to do is code and press the `Run` button.

Comment: I test in Console, not in IDE

Comment: Anyway, I find out how to fix this. Just use the following >java -classpath testpack.jar;. Hello
end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it could be many things, If you're a beginner in Java I'd reccomend starting with an IDE, howver if you dont want this then here is a link on [3 ways to resolve NoClassDefFoundError in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html)

Here is also an extract from another user who explains why this error occurs:

> I always get that error when I create a class file in a package and
>   then attempt to run the program from within the package. The solution
>   is to go up one level in your file system so that you are on the level
>   of the package, not of the package contents.
>
> For example, if your package's name is greetings and your class file's
>   name is HelloWorld, your program contains the line:
>
> package greetings;
>
> The package name corresponds to a directory in your file system, e.g.
>   C:\Java\greetings. Your class file is within that directory, i.e. its
>   file name is C:\Java\greetings\HelloWorld.class.
>
> If you position to c:\Java\greetings and then execute:
>
> java HelloWorld
>
> you get a NoClassDefFound error. If you go up one directory, in this
>   case to C:\Java, instead of C:\Java\greetings, and then do this:
>
> java greetings.HelloWorld
>
> your program should work for you.